# Обнаружены символы за пределами инструкции

Tags: sql, ms-access

Необходимо было перехватить код, только что добавленной строки, использовал @@Identity т.к база данных находится на access

```
INSERT INTO [Автошкола]
([Фамилия], [Имя], [Отчество], [Пол], [Гражданство], [Дата_рождения], [Кол-во], [Категория], [Дата_приёма_на_работу], [Код_прохождения], [Код_принятия], [Код_должности], [Адрес_проживания], [Телефон])
VALUES        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Выдаёт ошибку о том что "Обнаружены символы за пределами инструкции"
Крик души!

Answer (score 0):

Выполняйте команды отдельно в коде.

```
command.Execute "INSERT INTO [Автошкола] ..."

res = command.Execute "SELECT @@IDENTITY" ....
```